# Converter JSON em objeto com GSON

Tags: json, rest, gson

Estou com um webservice pronto, que retorna um JSON de um objeto, ótimo, funcionando: Aqui está o JSON retornado:

```
{"Opa":{"nome":"Teste1234"}}
```

Esse JSOn é da seguinte classe:

```
public class Opa {
public String nome = "Basico";
}
```

o GSON simplesmente cria o objeto com os valores null. Código abaixo:

```
GsonBuilder etaB = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson pegador = etaB.create();
Opa teste1 = pegador.fromJson("{\"Opa\":{\"nome\":\"Teste1234\"}}",Opa.class);
```

Coloquei a string direto no metodo fromJson acima pra exemplificar.

O meu problema é:

O nome da classe no inicio "Opa":{} - Caso eu mande sómente {"nome":"Teste1234"} aí ele consegue fazer a conversão.

Comment: Qual linguagem está usando? Se sim veja http://blog.wektabyte.com/converter-objetos-java-em-json-e-vice-versa-com-gson/

Answer (score 0):

quando você tem um json com a seguinte estrutura:

```
`{ "Opa": {} }`
```

você está informando que possui um `objeto` que possui uma `propriedade` chamada `Opa`, e esta `propriedade` armazena outro `objeto`.

então à sua estrutura requer duas classes.:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public Oba Oba;
}

public class Opa {
    public String nome;
}
```

por fim, você pode deserializar da seguinte forma:

```
pegador.fromJson("{\"Opa\":{\"nome\":\"Teste1234\"}}", Wrapper.class);
```